# Convert curl GET to javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, curl, parse-platform, react-native

I am able to successfully retrieve an object from parse using command below:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id:1231231231" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 131231231" \
-G \
--data-urlencode 'where={"uid":"12312312"}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/birthday`
```

But I'm struggling converting it to javascript, using the code below I will get response with a *status* of `200`. I assume error is converting *data-urlencode* to *data*:

```
var getObject = function {
    var url = "https://api.parse.com";
    url += '/1/classes/birthday';

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': '12122',
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': '12121',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: '{"where":{"uid":"12312312"}}'

    })
    .then(function(request, results) {
        console.log(request)
        console.log(results)
    })
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `fetch` but it looks like there should not be single quotes around the `data`, like `data:{"where":{"uid":"12312312"}}`

Comment: @chiliNUT Just tried that, same response either way, thanks though: `body: (... ), bodyUsed: false, headers: Headers, ok: true, status: 200, statusText: "OK", type: "cors", url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/birthday"`

Comment: so did you fix this? im trying something similar, but i no matter what i put in data, even malformed json, i get all the items from class/Run. its not filtering anything, or giving me errors. when i do the same with curl, i get "json error", which is the correct thing to get

Comment: Why not just use https://www.wireshark.org/ (Wireshark) and see for yourself what's being sent, before trying to produce the same output?

Answer (score 49):

Since I often wanted to do this, I made https://kigiri.github.io/fetch/ , you can copy / paste a curl command it will give you the fetch code.

You can checkout the source if you want to use it differently.

> **edit:** The feature was added to chrome devtools
>   [image: devtool-as-fetch-opts]
>    Thanks chrome dev team

Comment: @user3696212 I added the support for -F, try it out and tell me if you have any issue with it.

Comment: Bless you for making that!

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! Thank you friend :)

Comment: Really great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

Ok so basically you need another then. So it has something to do with promises. I figured it out after reading this awesome article http://blog.gospodarets.com/fetch_in_action/

What you need to do is this

```
var getObject = function {
  var url = "https://api.parse.com";
  url += '/1/classes/birthday';

  return fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'X-Parse-Application-Id': '12122',
          'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': '12121',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data: '{"where":{"uid":"12312312"}}'

  })
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(data){
    console.log(data); //this will just be text
    var data_obj = JSON.parse(data);
    return data_obj
  })

}
```

I don't really understand why you have to return response.text(). Again it has something to do promises

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise

Because when I access response.text() from the first then. It returns a promise.

Hopefully some other kind gentleman can comment and explain why returning response.text() turns the promise into the data you need.

--EDIT--

I added some returns to show how you can have getObject return out the response data as an object. So

```
var d = getObject();
```

will return the response as a js object now.

Comment: Yes Charles! I love you :D